# Django-haystack search with whoosh returns 'No results' debugging unsuccessful

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am new to Django and Haystack. I have done everything suggested on the "getting started" page of the Haystack Documentation and on the debugging page, but I cannot see where my error lies.  `sqs.count()` returns 0 even though `rebuild_index` seems to work, giving the right number of entries in the tables being indexed and producing index files into the `whoosh_index` directory.

`search_indexes` has the required `text =` lines, I have a search_sites.py, I have changed the settings.py and urls.py, and I have [model_name]_text.txt files in the right directory.

We are working on a university server where we had to update Django to work with Haystack after we installed Haystack because we realized it was an incompatible version (1.1 not 1.5) - could the old Django have messed with the Haystack installation somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The following code will show you what has been indexed - replace  with the correct path for your setup.

```
from whoosh.index import open_dir
ix = open_dir('<yourapp>/whoosh_indexes')
from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(ix.searcher().documents()))
```

If that doesn't shed any light you will have to post more details of your code - particularly the search_indexes.py

Comment: What do you do if this shows you the right list of stuff, but still you get no results?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem obvious but I had the same error and reading from http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging.html I found out that I was using the wrong attribute name for the returned objects.

```
   ensure that {{ result.object.title }} corresponds to your model field
   for instance I had name as the model filed but kept wondering why I didn't get results.
   I had to change to {{ result.object.name }} to list my results
```

name was the needed attribute. Hope this helps someone.